# firebase notification when app is killed and click on notification while getting null android

Tags: android

please help me below the code of firebase notification come in mobile while the application in killed mode after a click on notification getting not getting intent .
  stape 1:

```
@SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
 }

 stape 2 :

 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    /*PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);*/
    notificationIntent.putExtra("payload", "payload");
    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 
   PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    notification
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) // can use any other icon
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setContentIntent(sentPI)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setNumber(3); // this shows a number in the notification dots
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    assert notificationManager != null;
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

add these lines at the onCreate() method of your MainActivity.class

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    for (String key : extras.keySet()) {
        Object value = extras.get(key);
        Log.d(Application.APPTAG, "Extras received at onCreate:  Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
    }
    String title = extras.getString("title");
    String message = extras.getString("body");

}
```